# react dynamically override child render

Tags: reactjs

I have the following reactJS component structure

```
<Parent>
    <Child1/>
</Parent>
<Parent>
    <Child2/>
</Parent>
```

the children have a function that performs different API calls.. Until thats finished, the child is not ready to be rendered. So is there a way for me to have the parent display 
"waiting for data..." 
and call the method in the child to do the API call

in the child i would like to have a simple render method which does not have to check if the get API call has completed or not

I have tried two approaches but both unsuccessful

1. Try call a method in the child with out rendering it.. React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child)=>child.doAPICall()) but this child does not seem to have its functions available
2. Override the render function dynamically so it renders nothing, then after the children have completed the API calls to swap the render mthod back

   React.Children.map(this.props.children, (item, i) =>
   (React.cloneElement(item, { 
       render: () => false
     })))
   this will allow me to override props but not the render method

Any advice would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1):

You should do a conditional render. I would suggest in one of the following two ways:

- Either in the parent component. Do the necessary API calls to seed the data, and then render the children when the data is ready.
- Or in the children. Do the data calls (for example in componentDidMount), and then render the data when it's ready. Until then render something else, ie some text or an image that says 'Loading'.

Whether or not you decide to conditionally render the children from the parent, or if you simply decide to do a conditional render within the children's render themselves, it would look something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.data? 
            <div>{this.state.data.somedata}</div>
        :
            <div>Loading...</div>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

or even:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.data.somedata}</div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Finally, an even more concise way to conditionally render is with this syntax:

```
render() {
  return(
      <div>
          {this.state.data && <div>{this.state.data.someField}</div>}
      </div>
   );
}
```

or for example

```
render() {
  return this.state.data && <div>{this.state.data.someField}</div>;
}
```

.. hopefully you get the idea :)

Comment: Thanks John.. I was hoping to avoid checking this.state.data on every child.. But i suppose its not the worse bit of duplication..

Comment: You could probably get clever with a higher order component if DRY is a priority.